# count, filter, over together

Tags: postgresql

Can you please tell me how can I get following result?

Table I have is:

```sql
create table as tbl 
(
event_id integer, 
payor varchar
)
```

`payor` and `event_id` both have duplicates. an event may contain more than 2 payor as well.

What I need is:
event_id column,
payor column,
a column that shows count of those events that are funded by more than 1 funder.

I want to keep the all the events in the result.
So first the query should do count of event_id by partition by event_id then look at that partitioned set and see whether the payor is different in that set for event_id and then give the result as count those events that have more than 1 payor.

below first 2 columns are part of my table and 3rd columns is what i want For e.g.

| event_id | payor | count | how count is calculated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2323 | a | 2 | count is 2 because 2323 has 2 unique payors a and b |
| 2323 | b | 2 | count is 2 because 2323 has 2 unique payors a and b |
| 5432 | b | 1 | count is 1 because 54332 has 1 unique payor b |
| 3423 | c | 1 | count is 1 because 3423 has 1 unique payor c |
| 211 | y | 1 | count is 1 because 211 has 1 unique payors y |
| 211 | y | 1 | count is 1 because 211 has 1 unique payors y |
| 600 | t | 2 | count is 2 because 600 has 2 unique payors t, o |
| 600 | 0 | 2 | count is 2 because 600 has 2 unique payors t, o |
| 600 | t | 2 | count is 2 because 600 has 2 unique payors t, o |

I have something like this below, but I do not know how to write something to look into each partition set and the payor. Following does not work

```sql
select event_id, payor,
(count(event_id) over(partition by event_id order by event_id) filter (where (count(payor) over(partition by event_id order by event_id)) >2))
from tbl
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: This post requires more debugging details, including a sample input table and the corresponding expected output.

Comment: hi @ lemon i have added a column above for explanation. first 2 columns are part of my table as a sample and 3rd columns is what i want and 4th column shows how the count should be calculated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

hi @Lemon and @Working pickle

eventually i was able to get what i need by using following query. i used dense_rank and paritioned that by event_id ordered by payor in cte
then i got max of dense_rank for each event_id.

thanks for your help on this.

```
with cte as 
(
select 
event_id, 
payor,
dense_rank() over(partition by event_id order by payor) as drnk
FROM tbl
order by  1)
    
select event_id, payor,
    max(drnk) over(partition by event_id order by event_id)
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT tbl.event_id, tbl.payor, tbl_count.payor_count
FROM tbl
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (event_id, payor) event_id, payor, COUNT(*) payor_count
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY event_id, payor
) tbl_count ON tbl_count.event_id = tbl.event_id AND tbl_count.payor = tbl.payor
WHERE tbl_count.payor_count > 1
```

1. grouped by event_id and payor to count their unique pair quantity
2. joined to same table so that events would not be lost, grouped
3. added where condition to filter by quantity

Comment: hi @working  pickle thanks for you comment. the count should only be calculated when payor is different for duplicate event_ids. this query when sued with full join gives count of all payors in an event_id

Comment: hi, did you join on both event_id and payor  columns? `ON tbl_count.event_id = tbl.event_id AND tbl_count.payor = tbl.payor`

Comment: hi Working pickle yes i exactly used what you mentioned above.

Comment: try adding `distinct on` both columns, I updated the answer. Unfortunately I can't test it myself right now, pls update me if it does not work

Comment: hi @working pickle it still does not give me the expected result